# Payment gateway response URL not working (CCAvenue)

Tags: codeigniter, payment-gateway, codeigniter-4, ccavenue

I am trying to integrate the CCAvenue payment gateway into my project everything works but when I cancel the payment or the payment is successful, the payment gateway sends data to the response link for that I have created a function and route for that.
the function works when I call using the browser but when payment gateways try to redirect to that link, the payment gateway does not find the link and I get a 404 error by payment gateway, The page you're looking for cannot be found!

I tried contacting the payment gateway and they say that the response page is not accessible by the payment gateway.

the routes I tried

```
$routes->post('response', 'Payment::paymentResponse');
or
$routes->match(['get', 'post'], 'response', [Payment::class, 'paymentResponse']);
```

Comment: Could you show the `paymentResponse` controller and how you are calling that route?

Comment: ok, it was the csrf filter causing a redirect so the CCAvenue gateway was unable to find the response page.
I disabled it and now everything works as expected.
is there a way to just bypass csrf for the payment gateway response?

any help, how can we achieve this? without removing csrf filter?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you everyone for the reply.

the solution is to disable CSRF just for that particular route/link
for ex.

```
public array $globals = [
        'before' => [
            'csrf' => ['except' => ['response']],
```

Answer (score 0):

Disable **CSRF** validation for the response page route.

1, Goto **app/Http/Middleware/VerifyCsrfToken.php**

2, Add the route in $except array

```
protected $except = [
        '/response',
    ];
```